# Pass Parameter From Main Report To Subreport

Tags: .net, reporting, reportviewer, subreport

I have an object datasource that I fill and use on my main report. I am trying to pass one of the properties from this object as a parameter to a subreport. The instructions I've read online are:

1. Right-click the subreport and click Subreport Properties.
2. Click the Parameters list item and then click Add to add a parameter.
3. Type in a name for the parameter and a value. (Here I've named it "MiscUpdates" which is the name of the object property I wish to pass to the subreport. The value is set to =First(Fields!MiscUpdates.Value, "dsReport")

Basically these are all of the instructions I've read and it does not provide me with an option to add this parameter as a value in a textbox within the subreport itself. How can I get access to this in the subreport?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I had to go into the Subreport first and add the parameter in the Report Data pane under Parameters with the same name first.